# How do I delete (or highlight) duplicate rows in Excel ONLY IF there are 4 or more instances?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel document that has over 300 rows of data. Column A is sorted by personnel names and I need to isolate only the people that have **less than 4** occurrences within the sheet.

Is there a way to delete all the names with 4 or more? Or, to highlight all the names with 4 or more?

Thank you!

Comment: Conditional formatting with `=countif` and a comparison would be one way to go.

Comment: When I do conditional formatting there is no option for =countif. Can you give me a few more directions on how to do this? I'd love to try it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we start with:

[image]

and we run this short macro:

```
Sub RowKiller101()
  Dim rKill As Range, r As Range, wf As WorksheetFunction
  Dim rBig As Range
  Set rBig = Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
  Set rKill = Nothing
  Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

  For Each r In rBig
    If wf.CountIf(rBig, r.Value) > 3 Then
      If rKill Is Nothing Then
        Set rKill = r
      Else
        Set rKill = Union(rKill, r)
      End If
    End If
  Next r

  If rKill Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
rKill.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

We will get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a non-VBA solution:

Put a formula like `=countif($A:$A,$A1)` in column B, your spreadsheet will now look something like this:

```
    A    B  
1  Joe   3  
2  Joe   3  
3  Joe   3  
4  Amy   5  
5  Amy   5  
6  Amy   5  
7  Amy   5
8  Amy   5
```

Then select `A1`, go to Conditional Formatting (custom rule) and put in the formula `=B1>=4`. Then apply the rule to as much as you need in column A. The lack of a `$` anchor means the rule will move along with the applied cell.

Answer (score 1):

Gary's Student: VBA solution to delete all but the <4 crowd
selwyth: Formula solution to filter to just the <4 crowd
This Answer: Conditional formatting solution to highlight just the <4 crowd

(You can also reference the [Office Support Article](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) about using formulas in conditional formatting which, as it turns out, uses `COUNTIF` for its example.)

1. Select the data range (in the example, I selected all of column `A:A`
2. On the `Home` ribbon, click `Conditional Formatting` and then `New Rule...`
3. Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
4. Input a formula like `=COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)<4`
   A. Change the `$A:$A` to whatever range in which you're searching for duplicates. For instance, it could be `$G$12:$G$48`. The `$` is important because it makes it an [absolute reference](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21) that doesn't change from cell to cell.
   B. Change the `$A1` to the *first* cell in the selected range. Note that there is only one `$` here because we only want the column to be absolute. We want the row number (`1`, in this case) to be relative to the current cell.
   C. The result is such that conditional formatting for `A1` will use the formula `=COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)<4` but, for `A2`, it will use the formula `=COUNTIF($A:$A,$A2)<4`. This is what controlling the absolute vs relative refences (`$` or no `$`) does for you.
5. Click the `Format...` button and select whatever formatting you like. In this case, I chose to highlight the cells in a yellow background.
6. Click `OK` to close the conditional formatting window and see the results

[image: Screenshot for Steps 1-5]

Note that, because of the way I did this, all the blank rows are highlighted, too. If that doesn't work for you, there are a few ways to fix it. I recommend Option 1 because it's a simple way to keep up with your list as it grows.

1. Change the formula you use in Step 4 to `=AND($A1<>"",COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)<4)`
2. Instead of selecting all of column `A:A` like I did in Step 1, select just your data range.
3. After the conditional formatting is created, go back into the `Conditional Formatting Rules Manager` (Home ribbon > Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules...) and change the `Applies to` field from `=$A:$A` to something specific like `=$A$1:$A$19`. This is the same result as using Option 2 but it lets you change it after the fact.